# Select multiple rows & colums in datatable where value occurs more than once

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a table like the picture below:

[image]

I am trying to return a result that will return all rows (and columns) where product codes are the same

I have not really used linq before and have playing around with some group by clauses but havent gotten really anywhere, except returning the each individual part code

```
var GetProductsRows = from DataRow dr in table.Rows
    group dr by dr.Field<string>("Product Code") into g
    select g;
```

Somehow I think I am treading water a little out of my depth

Comment: What do you want to return for each grouped `Product Code` from `Description`, `Stock` and `Price`? `Max`, `Min` ?? Or, you want just the `Product Code`?

Comment: What do you want your returned values to look like?

Comment: I would like to return each entire row that has a duplicate part number. Does that make sense? So for example the above table would return all rows except for part04 row

Comment: You must Group by the Product Code, Description, Price and Sum(Stock)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nested linq query should do the trick:

```
var GetProductsRows = from DataRow dr in table.Rows
    group dr by dr.Field<string>("Product Code") into gp
    from rows in gp where gp.Count() > 1 select rows;
```

Basically this will select all rows that belong to groups whose count is greater than one.

Comment: close! this is only returning rows that have the same value in each column. whereas I am looking for returning an entire row where the value is the same in only the "Product Code" column. Rows may have a different description / stock / price value but the same Product Code.

Comment: Are you sure? Because the grouping condition is only comparing the "Product Code" field, and in my tests it worked as expected, i.e., rows with the same "Product Code" field but not necessarily the same value in other fields were returned it the result.

Comment: my bad Thomas. when applying to my actual DataTable some of the product codes I was trying to return had white space at the end of the string. thanks for your help

Comment: It's all right. Just in case you're not aware about it, the [String.Trim Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx) can be used to easily remove leading and trailing white spaces from your string.